# How to update a BindingSource based on a modified DataContext

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext, bindingsource

In my application, I extract the Data of a Linq To SQL DataContext into a dictionary for easy use like so:

```
Jobs = dbc.Jobs.ToDictionary(j => j.Id, j => j);
```

Then I bind this dictionary to a BindingSource:

```
bsJob.DataSource = jobManager.Jobs.Values.ToList();
```

I refresh the DataContext and the Dictionary regularly for when new Jobs are added to the database (whether directly through the local application or the application running on a different machine):

```
dbc.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, dbc.Job);
Jobs = dbc.Job.ToDictionary(j => j.Id, j => j);
```

How can I update the BindingSource to accommodate the changes as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the relation from the Jobs class to the Customer class, so I'll assume you meant to type that and not jobManager.Customers.Values.ToList();

Assuming you already have some sort of event triggering your refresh, since you mentioned you updated "regularly", you can assign a new value to the BindingSource.DataSource property at that time just like you did originally.

```
dbc.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, dbc.Customer);
Customers = dbc.Customer.ToDictionary(c => c.Id, c => c);
bsJob.DataSource = jobManager.Jobs.Values.ToList();  //Assuming this statement was correct
```

Comment: Ha, how embarassing! Of course, I meant Job the whole way, this was just a silly Copy&Paste error as I've got several Objects I handle this way and I mixed the code up. So there is no nifty way to do this, just reassign as DataSource?

Comment: AFAIK... at least that's how I do it.  Of course, there's usually multiple ways of doing things, some more creative that others.

If it were my code, I'd just have a Jobs Property and have it refresh on get{}.

private JobClass _JobList;
public JobClass JobList
{
   get
   { 
      _JobList = dbc.Jobs.ToDictionary(j => j.Id, j => j);
      return _JobList;
}
   set{ _JobList = value;}
}

Then you can just assign that to your DataSource

bsJob.DataSource = JobList;

Comment: I used this approach before, but I thought it might be smarter to cache the Jobs until it's refreshed from the database (which happens every 30 seconds).

Comment: If you're accessing the property more than once every 30 seconds then I'd only automatically load from the database if the private property is null.

private JobClass _JobList;
public JobClass JobList
{
get
{
if(_JobList == null) 
_JobList = dbc.Jobs.ToDictionary(j => j.Id, j => j);
return _JobList;
}

set
{
_JobList = value;
}
}

if you want to update the contents then assign a new value to the private property

_JobList = dbc.Jobs.ToDictionary(j => j.Id, j => j);

Comment: Or I could assign null and access the Property, so I wouldn't have to know from where or how it is updated, but I could update it nevertheless. Great idea, I'll do that! Thanks.

Comment: After some consideration it does not seem so great to change the behaviour of assigning null anymore, especially considering when other people work with that code. ;)